# Merging questions to include more words

Tags: discussion

I've just asked a question ([How is this screw head called?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/39727/how-is-this-screw-head-called)) which has been marked as duplicate. Indeed, after seeing the original one, I realize it had been asked.

The reason I had not found it was because I used the terms "screw" and "tamper proof" when searching, while the question uses "bolt" and "security".

How can I merge my words into the older question, so that future searches will be able to find it? Should I just add a new answer with my words? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could suggest an edit to the question which includes these words, but there's the risk that the edit would be rejected if other users deemed it to be invalid in some way.

However, having a duplicate question with the different wording isn't necessarily a bad thing, and indeed could be regarded as a good thing. See:

> [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

for more information.

Both questions read naturally (more so than they would if one question tried to cover all terminology).